# Show text of a toolstrip

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, button

I would like to know how do I show the `toolstrip` text in a VB Form *(from what option in preferences in Visual Studio 2010 ).*

What I have is a `toolstrip` only with images and *hovering* the mouse i get the text set in `toolstrip` preferences.

I've tried setting the `ShowItemTooltips` option, but it seems that apply only for the `hover` mouse case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean, show the text from `toolstrip` to `statustrip` or some Label, TextBox?

Comment: i meant the toolstrip. It's ok now since @NYSystemsAnalyst gave me the answer i was lookin' for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the **DisplayStyle** for each ToolStripButton to **ImageAndText**.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! it worked :) I was setting the preferences for the toolstrip instead of each ToolStripButton